# Apache Redirection {QUERY_STRING} input is empty in Rewrite Cond

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I would like to perform redirection based on QUERY_STRING parameter, for example:

from this URL 
mySite.com/index.html#query?id=1111

to this URL
mySite.com/newSite/query#query?id=111

I searched online on how to use the parameter in RewriteCond, and below is my configuration:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query?id.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html.*$
RewriteRule /index.html(.*) /newSite/query%(QUERY_STRING)
```

I have the trace debug mode on, and noticed that the condition got fired, but the input is empty, as showed in screen below

[rewritecond input = ''](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLYJ7.png)

Can anyone please advise on this issue? Thank!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know (working in php), the text after the anchor (#) is never actually send to the server.

your conditions will always fire, even if there are no characters after /index.html, this is because you used a 0-or-more quantifier (the * symbol), so if there are 0 or more of any character (. symbol), it will trigger the rewrite rule

problem is that there is no actual input (as you noticed :))